# Group avarage actions per day in a SQL query for MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

i have a table which has fields like this:

```
id | created | action_type | value
```

Created is a timestamp in a varchar field. What i need to do is to calculate the average actions per day in one query. All need to be grouped by one day.

so i need something like this

```
2017-10-01 : 15 
2017-10-02 : 20
```

How can i achieve this? 
:)

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you just want a `group by`:

```
select date(created), count(*)
from t
group by date(created);
```

Comment: this gives me a null in the date(created) column?

Comment: i have found the solution my self.
You have to convert the Timestamp with FROM_UNIXTIME and then pass it to the date function. Then it works :)